# Can't find children of transform in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, children

I am try to find the children of the transform that I insantiate. This is my code:

```
public Transform GetLevel(int _currentLevel)
{
    string levelName = "Level" + _currentLevel;
    Transform level2Load = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Levels/" + levelName)) as Transform;
    Debug.Log(level2Load.childCount);
    return level2Load;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LevelLoading.GetLevel (Int32 _currentLevel) (at Assets/Resources/Scripts/LevelScripts/LevelLoading.cs:10)

Does anybody know why?

edit*

The wierd thing is that it does find the transform and instantiates it. But it can't find the chrildren.

The children do appear in the scene, and if I attatch an script to the transform that looks for the children it finds them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: which line is it referring to?

Comment: this line Debug.Log(level2Load.childCount);

Comment: does this work? `Transform level2Load = (Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Levels/" + levelName))as GameObject).transform;`

Comment: Transform level2Load = (MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Levels/" + levelName)) as GameObject).transform; works! Could you explain why?

Comment: no idea, i thought actually the `MonoBehaviour` part was the problem, hence my answer

Comment: Sorry if you were planning to give my answer, @Andrew, I only saw your unedited "does this work?" comment without the code before I submitted it. Although I hope the explanation helps.

Comment: this is honestly a weird problem.. does this work? `Transform level2Load = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Levels/" + levelName), typeof(Transform))as Transform;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is from:

```
Debug.Log(level2Load.childCount);
```

`level2Load` is `null`. Therefore trying to access its `childCount` results in a null reference exception. This is probably due to the `as` in:

```
MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Levels/" + levelName)) as Transform;
```

Because [`as` tries to typecast and returns null if the typecast is invalid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx), I think your issue is that the instantiated object is a `GameObject`, not a `Transform`.

Try casting to `GameObject` and using [`.transform`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html) instead:

```
GameObject level2Load = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Prefabs/Levels/" + levelName)) as GameObject;
return level2load.transform;
```

Comment: I don't understand why this would be the case though, since Unity states that you can do `Instantiate(...) as Texture2D`

Comment: I'm fairly sure the type of what you get from `Instantiate` depends on what the asset is. If you give it a path to a texture, you get a `Texture2D`, if you give it a path to a prefab, you get the root `GameObject`. `as` doesn't do *conversion*, just *typecasting*, if that makes sense. **Edit:** I noticed the `as` docs do refer to it as conversion between compatible types--so it does conversion, but only on the type level. There's no way for Unity to see that `as` and deliver different objects based on that.